# using Double-Clicking Mouse in the Cell to copy the Value or Text to another Worksheet in the New Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in sheet1, by double clicking on any cell the entire row should populate in another sheet.I am able to do this but when the user clicks twice duplicate rows are populating in sheet2 to prevent this how to show a pop up saying this row is already exists or something like that

Here is my code . with the below code able to copy the data into new sheet by double clicking on any cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'double-click the mouse on the row to Sheet1 copies the entire row to Sheet2
Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 5)).Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

A pop up should show if particular row is already there like duplicate row any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks alot for your help

Comment: How would your code know the row already exists in the other sheet?  Is there some unique Id or combination of cells in the row which wouldd be used to match a row on the other sheet?

Answer (score 1):

A COUNTIFS should be able to find matching A:E in the destination worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    'reference the destination worksheet
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    'check if all five cells in A:E match any row on Worksheets("Sheet3")
        If Application.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), Cells(Target.Row, "A"), _
                                .Range("B:B"), Cells(Target.Row, "B"), _
                                .Range("C:C"), Cells(Target.Row, "C"), _
                                .Range("D:D"), Cells(Target.Row, "D"), _
                                .Range("E:E"), Cells(Target.Row, "E")) = 0 Then
            'stop the in-cell edit
            Cancel = True
            'copy the row from Sheet1 copies the entire row to Sheet3
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 5)).Copy _
              Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox "duplicate"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Another approach might be to always copy the cells across then RemoveDuplicates.